# Why does BIP141 define both virtual transaction size and weight?

Tags: segregated-witness, blocksize, transaction-weight, block-weight

Why does BIP 141 (segwit) [define both *virtual transaction size* and *weight*](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#Transaction_size_calculations)?

Weight seems to be just four times virtual transaction size (or vice versa, depending on what you define first). Why are both needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The transaction limit under segwit is derived solely from the *transaction weight* and the *block weight limit* of 4,000,000 weight units.

*Virtual transaction size* was not used for the limit calculation because it is fractional when computed accurately. Bitcoin Core only uses integers in the consensus code and thus transitioned to *transaction weight* with the activation of segwit.

*Virtual transaction size* is merely provided as a convenient way of comparing segwit's effective transaction size to pre-segwit transaction sizes.

---

Adding a quote of the section to clarify: [BIP141 specifies](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#Transaction_size_calculations) the following terms in regard to transaction size:

> *Transaction weight*
> is defined as Base transaction size * 3 + Total
> transaction size (ie. the same method as calculating Block weight from
> Base size and Total size).
>
> *Virtual transaction size*
> is defined as Transaction weight / 4 (rounded
> up to the next integer).
>
> *Base transaction size*
> is the size of the transaction serialized with
> the witness data stripped.
>
> *Total transaction size*
> is the transaction size in bytes serialized as
> described in BIP144, including base data and witness data.