# decoded raw transaction size & vsize mean?

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction

I have decoded my raw transaction using `decoderawtransaction`, I got these value

```
"size" => 259
"vsize" => 259
```

is that block size ?
if it does, is that byte or killo byte ?
I want to calculate miners fee based of block size

Comment: You probably want to calculate fees on transaction size, not block size. And size is the value you use as a basis, if you have non-segwit transaction. If segwit, use vsize and verify the underlying logic (quick search here in the forum!)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53623/5406