# Different fee rate units - sat/vB, sat perkw, sat perkb

Tags: transaction-fees, core-lightning, block-weight

While reading documentation of C-Lightning I found this in section about making onchain transactions with the wallet (funding and withdrawing the wallet):

> **feerate**  is  an optional feerate to use. It can be one of the strings
> urgent (aim for next block), normal (next 4 blocks or so) or slow
> (next 100 blocks or so) to use lightningd's internal estimates: normal
> is the default. Otherwise, feerate is a number, with an optional
> suffix: **perkw means the number is  interpreted  as
> satoshi-per-kilosipa  (weight), and perkb means it is interpreted
> bitcoind-style as satoshi-per-kilobyte**. Omitting the suffix is
> equivalent to perkb.

I am used to sats/vB as this is used by most wallets I know and also by e.g. blockstream.info explorer. What would be equivalent of, lets say, 20 sat/vB in perkw and perkb units?

My understanding is that 1 sat/vB = 1000 perkw, so 20 sat/vB would be 20000 perkw. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, one vbyte [vB] is equal to four weightunits [wu]. The people working on C-Lightning use "sipa" interchangeably for a weightunit.

1,000 sat/kvB = 1 sat/vB
1 sat/vB = 0.25 sat/wu
0.25 sat/wu = 250 sat/kwu

20 sat/vB = 5,000 sat/kwu

Also see: [Is there a difference between bytes and virtual bytes (vbytes)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89418/5406)