# Is it possible for the `size` and `vsize` to be the same for a valid segwit (bech32) transaction?

Tags: segregated-witness, transaction-weight, block-weight

I'm aware that for non-segwit transactions, [`vsize` is always the same as `size`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89387/127763). But is it possible for a valid transaction to include `size`=`vsize` when involving segwit inputs/outputs?

This particular query is motivated by a need to debug an 'invalid signature' error associated with a raw transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With segwit outputs, yes. Segwit outputs do not have a witness that could get discounted.

With segwit inputs, in theory possibly, but in practice no. Every standard segwit input today has a non-empty witness, and thus will get a discount.